# How to tell pip to parallelise compilations

Tags: python, gcc, pip, g++, python-poetry

Whenever I build containers for my Python project on my desktop machine, it takes *forever* to install all of the Python dependencies.  For the most part, the biggest slowdown comes from packages that require compilations, like numpy, lxml, etc.

The thing is, looking at my CPU stats, only 1 of my 16 cores is ever busy through these bottlenecks, so I'm thinking that there must be a way for me to indicate to the installer running `gcc` or `g++` that there are more resources that could be used.

I know that if I was compiling things directly myself using make, I could use `make -j 24`, but since my only interface is `pip install -r requirements.txt` (or more often lately `poetry install`), I'm thinking there must be an environment variable I can set before the installation?  Something like `MAKE_JOBS=24` or `GCC_PARALLEL=16`?

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You can use `MAKEFLAGS="-j 24"`.

Comment: The compilation step shouldn't have to happen each time the containers are rebuilt. I would recommend looking into mounting _pip_'s cache directories into the containers or something like that to avoid repeating the compilation steps. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know, building a container doesn't allow for the mounting of temporary volumes.  If you want something in the container, you need to `COPY` it in.  Besides, being able to use the full CPU when building things remotely (like in a CI) would be good to know anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, `COPY` (my mistake). Well you could need both, but having access to prebuilt distributions in the _dockerfile_ is what will get you the most long term gain, I would assume. Also how come the _wheels_ of numpy, etc. directly from _PyPI_ are not used? The whole thing seems strange to me.

Comment: Well I just tried `MAKEFLAGS="-j 24" poetry install` and while there was a brief moment of multi-cpu usage during the `Installing numpy (1.19.1)` step, the vast majority of time is still spent on one core.  I'm not sure why it has to be compiled rather than installed as a binary.  The `pyproject.toml` file simply lists `numpy = "^1.19.0"` and `poetry install` performs a build.

Comment: "_I'm not sure why it has to be compiled rather than installed as a binary._" It depends if the Python interpreter is supported by one of the wheels [here](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.19.1/#files). You can find out by checking the list of tags of the Python interpreter: `python -m pip debug --verbose`. -- If by chance you are using a Docker container based on _Alpine Linux_, then you might want to change, as it uses a diferent standard C library: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/ -- Nonetheless you should think about making the cache for _pip_ (and others) available

Comment: Well I'm using Alpine explicitly because I'm trying to keep the image size small, so switching to another distribution or copying in the pip cache would have the same unwanted effect.

Comment: For one you can use _multi step builds_, to avoid keeping the build artifacts (pip cache) in the final image. And then other base images are not that much bigger in the end, it might have been true for a while that Alpine was meaningfully smaller but I don't think it's the case anymore. Lastly you have to choose what has more worth to you, reducing the build time or reducing the storage size. Docker is good-ish at reusing the layers, so the disk usage is not that big, if your Dockerfile are well written. But I don't know what your requirements are.

Comment: Suggestion: maybe add some docker specific tags and show your Dockerfile. Seems to me like there is a lot of room for improvement. You say you want Alpine for the small size, but then you have to add a whole build toolchain inside, don't you? That takes a lot of space. Which is fine if you have multi step builds, but it doesn't seem to be the case. So do you uninstall the build tool chain afterwards? That probably invalidates tons of Docker layer optimizations, doesn't it?